# H2 tag overlapping text

Tags: html, css

I spent the majority of my time off today trying to figure out why this h2 tag is overlapping with the text below it?

Here is the same scenario I am working with: [code pen](http://codepen.io/Fabian-Amran/pen/QNZdQR)

```css
body {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.sections-entry-title h2 {
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: #DD3333;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sections-entry-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #bb3333;
    height: 64px;
}
div {
    display: block;
}


.width-80 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 80px 10px 60px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="sections-entry-title"><h2>This is a very long title this is a very long title this is a very ling title again very very long even longer than you thought actually super long long title that it doesnt make sense</h2></div>

<div class="width-80">
text text text texttettext text text text textext text text textext text text text textt textxt text text text text text.<p></p>
<p><b>Choose an option to get started</b></p>

</div>  
  
</body>
```

No matter what I do I just can't get the h2 tag to just take its own space rather than overlap on the text below it.

UPDATE: the reason why I set the class below to 64px is because I want to create a horizontal behind the h2 tag.

```
.sections-entry-title {
   height: 64px;
}
```

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve, but if the title gets too long then the h2 tag over laps with the text below it. Should have posted this screen shot earlier - my mistake]

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be more specific because you just lost me a reputation. This question is already short enough how short do you want me to make it?

Comment: @FabianAmran at class .sections-entry-title you have set height as 64px so make it min-height : 64px; will solve the issue

Comment: It wasn't intentionally. Now I know.

Comment: @FabianAmran, no problem. Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Good lord, 5 people with the same answer, does no one bother to read them before posting?

Comment: @Chris Well, now I know what caused the problem, I just need to figure out a way to include a horizontal line behind the h2 tag without having to set the parents height to 64px

Comment: @FabianAmran you mean like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwaRgB. There is a red line above h2 now.

Comment: Not quite I want the horizontal line to appear as if its behind the h2 tag but at the same time not to have the h2 tag overlap the text below it.

Comment: @FabianAmran check my answer below. I have added a new **Codepen**

Answer (score 2):

Your `.sections-entry-title` has a static height of `64px`, remove this and it displays fine:

```css
body {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.sections-entry-title h2 {
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: #DD3333;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sections-entry-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #bb3333;
}
div {
    display: block;
}


.width-80 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 80px 10px 60px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sections-entry-title"><h2>This is a very long title this is a very long title this is a very ling title again very very long even longer than you thought actually super long long title that it doesnt make sense</h2></div>

<div class="width-80">
text text text texttettext text text text textext text text textext text text text textt textxt text text text text text.<p></p>
<p><b>Choose an option to get started</b></p>

</div>
```

EDIT: Updated to also include the bar in the background of the `.sections-entry-title`:

```css
body {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.sections-entry-title h2 {
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: #DD3333;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sections-entry-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #bb3333;
    position: relative;
}
.sections-entry-title:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  content: " ";
  top: 64px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -40px;
  right: -40px;
}
div {
    display: block;
}


.width-80 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 80px 10px 60px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sections-entry-title"><h2>This is a very long title this is a very long title this is a very ling title again very very long even longer than you thought actually super long long title that it doesnt make sense</h2></div>

<div class="width-80">
text text text texttettext text text text textext text text textext text text text textt textxt text text text text text.<p></p>
<p><b>Choose an option to get started</b></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The div    <div class="sections-entry-title"> is used to generate that horizontal line on the left and right side of the h2 tag. Any recommendations on how I can achieve this without having to set the height to 64px? I have tried to use pseudo before and after to accomplish this but it shows the horizontal line going through the h2 tag . I hope i made sense

Comment: @FabianAmran Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ws2m5hon/1/ - I've also updated my answer above. I've created an `:after` pseudo element which site 64px from the top of the `.sections-sentry-title`

Answer (score 0):

You have set your `section-entry-title` to have a height of `64px`. Remove it (or set it to `auto`) and it will work fine.

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwaRgB)

```
.sections-entry-title {
    height: 64px; <------ remove or set 'auto'
}
```

**Updated behavior**

The following will add a vertically aligned horizontal ruler that goes through the `h2` tag, as you described in the comments.

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqJZLg)

To do this, you can use css `:before` and `:after` selectors to make a line to the left and right of the `h2` respectively.

```
.sections-entry-title h2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #bb3333;
  width: 100%;
}

.sections-entry-title h2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #bb3333;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then, just set your `h2` to be positioned relatively with `position: relative`.

Comment: Very nice! The only problem is with the scroll

Comment: @FabianAmran What scroll?

Comment: @FabianAmran did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I posted the answer above a while back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's parent .sections-entry-title has a height of 64px, which prevents the document flow from giving the h2 element the space it would need.

```
.sections-entry-title {
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase or remove the height style for your `.sections-entry-title` div.

You have a `height: 64px` style set on it.

By default, all elements have also an `overflow: visible` style which is causing the overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Height from class name .sections-entry-title or else make height as auto. because the height you specified is lesser than the content which u have.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out that all I needed to do was add a z-index value of -1 to .sections-entry-title h2, and create the horizontal line that is behind the h2 tag with pseudo:before.

Here is the code:

```
.sections-entry-title h2 {
   border: 3px solid;
   border-radius: 50px;
   color: white;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 20px 10px;
   background-color: #DD3333;
```

}

```
.sections-entry-title h2:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   margin-top: 20px;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   height: 3px;
   background: white;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Also, thank you everyone for pointing me to the right direction.

@Chris I am keeping this in my code, thanks

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```